# Codable Decodable JSON from String to Enum

Tags: swift, enums, codable, decodable

I'm trying to decode a JSON using codable. I'm wondering if there's a way to customize codable to return HelloModel's typeCustomer as type TypeOfCustomerEnum instead of String?

Example:

```
{
"name": "Hello",
"lastName": "World",
"typeOfCustomer": "Student"
}

enum TypeOfCustomerEnum: String {
   let Student = "Student"
   let Paying = "Paying"
   let NonPaying = "Nonpaying"
}

struct HelloModel: Codable {
   let name: String
   let lastName: String
   let typeOfCustomer: TypeOfCustomerEnum // JSON for TypeOfCustomer is a String but TypeOfCustomer wanted
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `TypeOfCustomerEnum` must also conform to `Codable` and the cases (must be cases) should be lowercased and the literal strings must match the JSON values

```
enum TypeOfCustomerEnum: String, Codable {
   case student = "Student"
   case paying = "Paying"
   case nonPaying = "NonPaying"
}

struct HelloModel: Codable {
   let name: String
   let lastName: String
   let typeOfCustomer: TypeOfCustomerEnum 
}
```